# How to get type from *types.Named

Tags: go, analysis

I'm trying to find function calls of `func`s that have `context.Context` as first parameter.

I've been able to do what's shown below but I'm stuck at getting the underlying type from `*types.Named`. How can I do this?

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/printer"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/singlechecker"
)

var Analyzer = &analysis.Analyzer{
    Name: "addlint",
    Doc:  "reports integer additions",
    Run:  run,
}

func main() {
    singlechecker.Main(Analyzer)
}

func funcHasContextContextAsFirstParam(pass *analysis.Pass, expr ast.Expr) bool {
    t := pass.TypesInfo.TypeOf(expr)
    if t == nil {
        return false
    }

    bt, ok := t.Underlying().(*types.Signature)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }

    fmt.Printf("signature: %+v - %T\n", bt, bt)

    params := bt.Params()
    for i := 0; i < params.Len(); i++ {
        v := params.At(i)
        fmt.Printf("Type :  %T\n", v.Type())

        if named, ok := v.Type().(*types.Named); ok {
            // fmt.Printf("named : %v - %T\n", named.Obj(), named.Obj())
            fmt.Printf("named : %T\n", named)
            fmt.Printf("named.Obj() : %T\n", named.Obj())

            typ := named.Underlying()
            fmt.Printf("typ:  %T\n", typ.Underlying())

            if _, ok = typ.(context.Context); ok {
                fmt.Printf("context.Context type!\n")
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}

func run(pass *analysis.Pass) (interface{}, error) {
    for _, file := range pass.Files {
        ast.Inspect(file, func(n ast.Node) bool {
            be, ok := n.(*ast.CallExpr)
            if !ok {
                return true
            }

            fmt.Printf("call expression %+v\n", be)
            funcHasContextContextAsFirstParam(pass, be.Fun)

            return true
        })
    }

    return nil, nil
}
```

That's the output I'm getting:

```
call expression &{Fun:foo Lparen:6160580 Args:[c 0xc0003c5780 0xc0003c57c0] Ellipsis:0 Rparen:6160596}
signature: func(ctx context.Context, n int, str string) - *types.Signature
Type :  *types.Named
named : *types.Named
named.Obj() : *types.TypeName
typ:  *types.Interface
```

Comment: The type assertion ain't possible. You need to check the TypeName's Name and Pkg().Name and possibly Pkg().Path

Comment: .. something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/ynoQ2Ako3Ms

Comment: Note that the go/types package provides *information about* types however it does not provide *instances* of those types, which is what you would need for the type assertion to work. If you need actual instances use reflection not ast.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks a lot! I've ended up with something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/60267033/675100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ended up with something like this:

```golang
func funcHasContextContextAsFirstParam(pass *analysis.Pass, expr ast.Expr) bool {
    t := pass.TypesInfo.TypeOf(expr)
    if t == nil {
        return false
    }

    bt, ok := t.Underlying().(*types.Signature)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }

    params := bt.Params()

    if params.Len() < 1 {
        return false
    }

    param := params.At(0)
    named, ok := param.Type().(*types.Named)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }

    namedObj := named.Obj()
    if namedObj.Name() != "Context" || namedObj.Pkg().Name() != "context" {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: `namedObj.Pkg()` may return `nil` I believe, for the builtin types like `string`, `int`, etc. so I would avoid `namedObj.Pkg().Name()` without first checking that it is *not* `nil`.